# Why can't I set value from my Global static class to a TextBlock XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, textblock

Here is XAML :

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock  x:Name="lbl1"  Text="1"  Margin="0,0,0,0"  FontSize="15" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <TextBlock  x:Name="lbl1Text" Text="{x:Static local:Globals.CurrentUser.FullName}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0"  FontSize="16" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontFamily="Arial"  />
</StackPanel>
```

As it is possible to see I'm trying to set currently Logged in user which is being hold in STATIC class in my project.

On form load I am setting that user like `Globals.CurrentUser = LoggedIn();`

And when I try to set this user to my TextBlock because I WANT TO display FullName who's currently logged in I am facing this issue :

Nested types are not supported: Globals.CurrentUser.FullName

This means That I can not access `property` `FullName` from my object `CurrentUser`?
And how could I fix this, and why is this happening?

P.S I know how to do it in code behind :

`lbl1.Text = Globals.CurrentUser.FullName;`  //and this might work

but I think "more right" approach is to bind it to TextBlock throught XAML

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `x:Static` syntax is (quote from documentation):

```
<object property="{x:Static prefix:typeName.staticMemberName}" .../>
```

where

> typeName: The name of the type that defines the desired static member.
>
> staticMemberName: The name of the desired static value member (a
>   constant, a static property, a field, or an enumeration value).

As you see - you only can use type name and ONE member name. Syntax like `Global.CurrentUser.FullName` is just not supported by this markup extension.

As a workaround you can use one-time binding like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Globals.CurrentUser}, Path=FullName, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

If you have more parts in your path, like `Globals.CurrentUser.Person.FullName` - you still can use binding. Since `x:Static` only supports one property - the rest will go in `Path`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Globals.CurrentUser}, Path=Person.FullName, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

`OneTime` binding is not required but is a good practice and even improves perfomance a bit (though a very little of course). Bindings usually are used to create some relation between target and source (like update target when source changes and so on). In this case we don't need all that, we just need to grab a value from source (static property) and assign to target (text block text). With `OneTime` we are telling wpf binding to do just that and not even bother with trying to find a way to listen to source property changes (which are not possible here anyway).

Comment: @Ekv Path=FullName is where you said which Property of Globals.CurrentUser should be binded? And what is that Mode=OneTime? And what would happen if I have object in a object so it might lookk like Globals.CurrentUser.Person.FullName? Than what should I write in Path=" "; So maybe in this situation better approach is to set it in code behind as I mentioned in question?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro I've updated answer with more info about that. As for setting in code behind - better not do that unless necessary. When in xaml - it's immediately visible that this TextBlock has this text. When in code behind - this information is not immediately obvious.